# How to Check Form valid or not using Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Is there any api available for check current form is valid or not using REDUX-FORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run code from official documentation - [sync validation](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/syncvalidation/)

But if you need to check validation asyncronously try this example - [redux form async validation](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/asyncvalidation/)

Btw you can also call 'this.props.validate()' to trigger form validation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. we can use isValid or isInvalid

```
import {
  isValid,
  isInvalid
} from 'redux-form'
```

isValid(formName:String) returns (state) => valid:boolean
Returns true if the form is valid, i.e. has no sync, async, or submission errors. The opposite of isInvalid.

isInvalid(formName:String) returns (state) => invalid:boolean
Returns true if the form is invalid, i.e. has sync, async, or submission errors. The opposite of isValid.